# How to unzip more than 1 files from more than one sub-folders using perl script?

Tags: perl

I have more than one sub folders in the parent directory and each sub-folders has more than 10 zip files., for eg.
parent directory: /parentdir
sub directories : /parentdir/2011-01,2011-02... and until 2014-06, so on.. every month.

each sub-dir    : file1.zip, file2.zip, ... file10.zip

I want to use the perl script to unzip the all the files in the same sub-folders and remove the .zip file after extracting or just extract the file1.zip to file1

Could you please help to achieve this using PERL script in unix machine?

There is possibility to use the

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Uncompress::Unzip qw(unzip $UnzipError);

my $zipfile = $ARGV[0];
my $u = new IO::Uncompress::Unzip $zipfile
or die "Cannot open $zipfile: $UnzipError";

die "Zipfile has no members"
 if ! defined $u->getHeaderInfo;
}
```

but it give the option to uncompress/unzip only one file

#### Update for Answer by Miller

used the http://pkgs.org/centos-6/epel-i386/perl-Path-Class-0.25-1.el6.noarch.rpm.html and installed the rpm for Path::Class for per to recon., now still can't unzip the files in sub folders: IO::Uncompress::Unzip: input parameter not a filename, filehandle, array ref or scalar ref at unzipper.pl line 13

I have a parent folder api_parent_folder
     in sub-folders - 2014-01, 2014-02 ...

in the above script i have changed /parentdir to /mnt/api_parent_folder

I go the ever as below..

now still can't unzip the files in sub folders: IO::Uncompress::Unzip: input parameter not a filename, filehandle, array ref or scalar ref at unzipper.pl line 13

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) to interate through the directory structure:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class;
use IO::Uncompress::Unzip qw(unzip $UnzipError);

my $dir = dir('/parentdir');

while ( my $subdir = $dir->next ) {
    next unless $subdir->is_dir();
    while ( my $zipfile = $subdir->next ) {
        my $u = IO::Uncompress::Unzip->new("$zipfile")
            or die "Cannot open $zipfile: $UnzipError";

        die "Zipfile has no members" if !defined $u->getHeaderInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: used the http://pkgs.org/centos-6/epel-i386/perl-Path-Class-0.25-1.el6.noarch.rpm.html and installed the rpm for Path::Class for per to recon.,

Comment: @AruKaya Fixed by simply stringifying the $zipfile variable.  `my $u = IO::Uncompress::Unzip->new("$zipfile")`